# Medicinal water vs medicated water?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Which one should I use if a would like to refer to the water that has a healing effect due to its physical propertis or chemical components?

What is the difference between medicinal and medicated?

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**medicinal** means "having healing effects" whereas **medicated** means "having medicine added" or "having been given medicine".

So, water from a spring may be *medicinal*, even though it's nothing but water with naturally occurring minerals.

Soap which has had some germ-killing agents added to it could be called *medicated* soap.

A patient lying on a bed in a hospital might be sleepy because he has been *medicated*.